# UI-Router and Angularjs: main content isn't being displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

index.html:

```
<body>
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view></div>
    <div ui-view="footer"></div>
    <div id="footer" class="container" />
</body>
```

app.js:

```
.state('root', {
    url: '',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        'header': {
            templateUrl: 'views/header.html',
            controller: 'HeaderCtrl'
        },
        'footer': {
            templateUrl: 'views/footer.html'
        }
    },
    data: {
        requiresLogin: true
    }
}).state('root.home', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }
    },
    data: {
        requiresLogin: true
    }
})
```

So I have a header and footer that are properly being called and shown on the screen but for some reason, my home.html isn't being shown. For now, the home.html just includes a h1 heading of "Home" in it. It seems like space is being created for the content but it's just not showing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
.state('root', {
    url: '',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        'header': {
            templateUrl: 'views/header.html',
            controller: 'HeaderCtrl'
        },
        'main': {
            template: '<div>This is default main content placeholder</div>'
         },
        'footer': {
            templateUrl: 'views/footer.html'
        }
    },
    data: {
        requiresLogin: true
    }
}).state('root.home', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
        'main@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }
    },
    data: {
        requiresLogin: true
    }
})
```

and in index.html:

```
<body>
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view="main"></div>
    <div ui-view="footer"></div>
    <div id="footer" class="container" />
</body>
```

Comment: I tried that, still doesn't work... I can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Apparently it did - the issue was that my header has a sidebar which blocks off my main content...